# Combining multiple css3 selectors

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I know it's possible to combine some CSS3 selectors in jQuery but is it possible to combine all variations?

For example, I have a dynamically generated page that outputs an id with a unique identifier on the end, like videoPlayer-123 and I want to select all instances of that id who direct sibling is a paragraph tag. See example here:

```
$('p+div[id^=videoPlayer]').css('width','100%');
```

Does that work? Or is there a better way to do this?

Here is an example of what the HTML looks like:

```
<p>
    <span>
        <h2>Test video 1234</h2>
    </span>
</p>
<div id='videoPlayer_1234'>
    <div id='videoPlayer_1234_container'>
        <video controls="controls"><source src="test.mp4"/></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That will work. But why just not try? :)

Comment: I did try but it doesn't seem to effect it. That's why I was asking, seemed like it would have worked.

Comment: Need to see your HTML. Also make sure your divs aren't 100% in width already.

Comment: This is for our mobile site so they are at a fixed width of 620px normally.

Comment: works - http://jsfiddle.net/KQeew/

Comment: @Zoltan Toth: That's odd... you're not supposed to be able to have `h2` as a descendant of `p` because it'll automatically close the first `p` and thus become its sibling. But it looks like the closing `</p>` tag is creating a *second* `p` that acts as the preceding sibling of the `div`. At least in Firefox anyway. If I just leave the closing tag there it still works - http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/KQeew/2

Comment: @BoltClock In fact it's not really valid to include an `<h2>` in `<span>` too

Comment: This does work but not in this instances due to the dynamic video content. I'm going to create small work around. Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's perfectly valid and probably the best way to do it.